# Find columns in Pandas DataFrame containing dicts

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with several columns containing `dicts`. I am trying to identify columns that contain at least 1 dict.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'i': [0, 1, 2, 3],
                   'd': [np.nan, {'p':1}, {'q':2}, np.nan],
                   't': [np.nan, {'u':1}, {'v':2}, np.nan]
                 })


 # Iterate over cols to find dicts
 cdict = [i for i in df.columns if isinstance(df[i][0],dict)]
 cdict
 []
```

How do I find cols with `dicts`? Is there a solution to find cols with `dicts` without iterating over every cell / value of columns?

Answer (score 3):

You can do :

```
s = df.applymap(lambda x:isinstance(x, dict)).any()
dict_cols = s[s].index.tolist()
```

print(dict_cols)

```
['d', 't']
```

Comment: can you explain what this / applymap is doing under the hood?

Comment: applymap evaluate the provided function to each cell value, while apply evaluate to the entire column or row

Answer (score 2):

We can `apply` over the columns although this still is iterating but making use of `apply`.

```
df.apply(lambda x: [any(isinstance(y, dict) for y in x)], axis=0)
```

**EDIT:** I think using `applymap` is more direct. However, we can use our boolean result to get the column names

```
any_dct = df.apply(lambda x: [any(isinstance(y, dict) for y in 
 x)], axis=0, result_type="expand")
df.iloc[:,any_dct.iloc[0,:].tolist()].columns.values
```

Comment: this returns a boolean value. How do I find columns labels containing dict?

Comment: @kms I have edited to return column names